# Write a script to get 10 longest words chart and put them in separate file

Tags: string, powershell, get

I need to sort the words in a text file and output them to a file

```
Function AnalyseTo-Doc{
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Pad )

    $Lines = Select-String -Path $Pad -Pattern '\b[A-Za-zA-Яа-я]{2,}\b' -AllMatches
    $Words = ForEach($Line in $Lines){
        ForEach($Match in $Line.Matches){
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                LineNumber = $Line.LineNumber
                Word       = $Match.Value
            }
        }
    }
    $Words | Group-Object Word | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Count= $_.Count
            Word = $_.Name
            Longest= $_.Lenght
        }
    }
    | Sort-Object -Property Count | Select-Object -Last 10
}

AnalyseTo-Doc 1.txt
#Get-Content 1.txt | Sort-Bubble -Verbose | Write-Host Sorted Array: | Select-Object -Last 10 | Out-File .\dz11-11.txt
```

it's don't work

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? What happens instead?

Comment: List of top 10 most used words

Comment: And what happens instead?

Comment: I need the 10 longest words and it outputs the 10 most popular words

Comment: Not that it will affect your code sample,  but ```$_.Lenght``` should probably be ```$_.Length```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by the `Longest` property (consider renaming it to `Length`), which is intended to contain the word length, but must be redefined to `$_.Group[0].Word.Length`:<sup>Tip of the hat to [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel).</sup>

```bash
    $Words | Group-Object Word | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Count= $_.Count
            Word = $_.Name            
            Longest = $_.Group[0].Word.Length
        }
    } | 
    Sort-Object -Descending -Property Longest | 
    Select-Object -First 10
```

Note that, for conceptual clarity, I've used `-Descending` to sort by longest words first, which then requires `-First 10` instead of `-Last 10` to get the top 10.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Sorting by the `Count` property sorts by *frequency of occurrence* instead, i.e. by how often each word appears in the input file, due to use of [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object).
- `Longest= $_.Length` (note that your code had a typo there) accesses the length property of each *group object*, which is an instance of [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo), not that of the *word* being grouped by.

  - (Since such a `GroupInfo` instance has *no* type-native `.Length` property, but PowerShell automatically provides such a property as an [*intrinsic member*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members), in the interest of unified handling of collections and scalars. Since a group object itself is considered a scalar (single object), `.Length` returns `1`. PowerShell also provides `.Count` with the same value - *unless present type-natively*, which is indeed the case here: a `GroupInfo` object's type-native `.Count` property returns the count of elements in the group).
  - The `[pscustomobject]` instances wrapping the word at hand are stored in the `.Group` property, and since they're all the same here, `.Group[0].Word.Length` can be used to return the length of the word at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Function AnalyseTo-Doc{
param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Pad )

```
$Lines = Select-String -Path $Pad -Pattern '\b[A-Za-zA-Яа-я]{2,}\b' -AllMatches
$Words = ForEach($Line in $Lines){
    ForEach($Match in $Line.Matches){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            LineNumber = $Line.LineNumber
            Word       = $Match.Value
        }
    }
}
$Words | Group-Object Word | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        #Count= $_.Count
        Word = $_.Name            
        Longest = $_.Group[0].Word.Length
    }
} | 
Sort-Object -Descending -Property Longest | Select-Object -First 10 | Out-File .\dz11-11.txt
```

}

AnalyseTo-Doc 1.txt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).